# How to run a SQL command to change the products layouts in opencart

Tags: opencart

I was wondering if someone knows a command to change some of the product pages to a certain layout that you create in Opencart?

I have about 100 products I need to change their layouts to display certain things in the sidebar for the 100 products.

I created the layout in the admin area of Opencart 1.5.5.1. Honestly, having to go to each product (catalog > products) and select the design tab and select the Layout Override: to the choice of layout seems a little long to do!

Was hoping there is a simply SQL command to do. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing You would like to update all the products with the same layout, follow these steps:

1. Find out the Layout ID (let's say, it would be *15*).
2. Open up Your famous DB manager, let's say phpMyAdmin, while opening the window to type the SQL queries into it
3. Type in the following query and execute it:

```sql
UPDATE `product_to_layout` SET 
    `layout_id` = 15
WHERE 
    `product_id` IN (
        SELECT `product_id` FROM `product`
    )
```

(if You are using DB table prefixes, add it to the table names `product_to_layout` and `product`)

I am also supposing You only have a single store installation. The multistore could be a little different if You would like to set one layout for one store and another for other store.

If You have more layouts and would like to set one layout to a certain set of products You would have to modify the `WHERE` part to update only the concrete set of products.

Comment: Hi

Thanks for your comment. So the first part sounds easy. lol The Where I am not too sure of. Should I be simply adding the 'product_id' as the product ID's?... Im such a novice at SQL it annoys me that I am lol. 

Yes, I have one store, and yes I have multiple layouts, so I only wish to assign them (100) to a certain layout.

Comment: @Pandaboom - If you just want to do this to certain products and know the product_id of them, just use a comma separated list such as `23, 24, 25` etc using the SQL shadyyx has above in place of the `SELECT product_id FROM product`. It's worth remembering that you may need to add a prefix to the two table names if your store has one (usually `oc_`)